# Appending rows into table from dictionary

Tags: jquery, dictionary, html-table

I have a dictionary with (key,value) inside my jquery success function,

```
$.each(myDictioary, function (key, value) {
    alert(key + ' is ' + value);
}
```

I want all the Dictionary values in a var So I can append it my table..I have tried this so far, which didn't help..

```
var row = "";
$.each(myDictioary, function (key, Value) {
    row+ = "<td>"+value+"</td>"
}); 
$("#tableBodyId")
    .append($('<tr>')                                       
    .append($('<td>').text(row))
  )
```

But I think I am doing something wrong when I'm concatenating `<td>`.

```
row+
```

Please let me know how I can get all values from dictionary into my var row..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems

The concatenation operator `+=` should not have spaces in it.

You are creating an html string with multiple `<td>` in it but then appending a single `<td>` whose `text` is that html string

Try

```
var row = "";
$.each(myDictioary, function (key, Value) {
    row += "<td>"+value+"</td>"
}); 
var $tr = $('<tr>').append( row ); 
$("#tableBodyId").append($tr);
```

This assumes that you are only adding one row.

More details would need to be given if your dictionary contains data for more than one row